# I want to extract the data from txt files to csv file using python

Tags: python, loops, text

I want to extract all the text files data into csv files and have to plot the graphs in python. I know how to read the file, lines , stripping out extra spaces in python but I don't know the logic to extract the data from input files to output file. I am attaching the images of input file structure, required output format csv file and also I am attaching my code. any suggestion to improve code is welcome. Thank you guys.

input.txt

```
# started on Thu Jan 23 21:03:30 2020

Performance counter stats for './a.out in_5K.fluid in_100K.fluid --verbose':

     13.677360      task-clock (msec)         #    0.987 CPUs utilized          
             0      context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
         1,062      page-faults               #    0.078 M/sec                  
   5,86,68,441      cycles                    #    4.289 GHz                    
  17,13,37,074      instructions              #    2.92  insn per cycle         
   3,14,80,047      branches                  # 2301.617 M/sec                  
        26,042      branch-misses             #    0.08% of all branches        

   0.013853468 seconds time elapsed
```

required_output_format.csv

```
instructions,task-clock (msec),context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,branches,branch-misses
171337074,13.677360,0,0,1062,58668441,31480047,26042
```

My code so far:

```
file = open("input.txt")
lines = file.readlines()

count = 1
for line in lines:
    line=line.strip()
    if(count>=6 and count <=13 ):
        words = line.split('#')
        data = words[0].strip().split(" ")
        value=""
        raw_value = data[0]
        values=raw_value.split(',')
        for i in values:
            value=value+i
        print(value.strip() )
        heading = data[-2]+data[-1]
        print(heading.strip())
    count += 1
```

Comment: "can someone help me guys" - what kind of help are you expecting? What's your code and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have no Idea how to do the job. I want which library I need to use. how to remove commas in the numbers. how to remove extra lines. I need the way to do the job. I have just code to read the file that's it. @ForceBru

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and I hope you find the help you are looking for. But right now, the question is worded in a way that doesn't tell me what kind of help you want. Have you written some code, and it doesn't work the way you expect? Then edit your question to show your code, and what happens when you run it, and how that is not what you want.

Comment: More on improving the question: well done for including the text of `input.txt` and `output.csv`. But please delete the screen grab images, of those same files in an editor. They don't add any information. Images aren't a helpful way of presenting text files.

Comment: Explore reading text file in python and processing the string and then the obtained values you can save it in files seperated by comma. Asking questions on this platform comes after you have tried and explored the options available on internet/ stackoverflow and still are stuck.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. can you please review my questions. Thank you.....

Comment: Big improvement in the question, @sudheer. But I think some of the spacing for the `input.txt` and `output.csv` file contents got mangled. Double-check that perhaps?

Comment: Sudheer, did @leilaAbdelrahman's answer help you? Then reward them by upvoting their answer, and by clicking the check mark symbol to accept their answer. That's what makes Stack Overflow work for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple files, the best thing would be to have a loop and use a csv writer.

```
import csv


#initialize an array with all the csv files you will write to

txtfiles = ['text1.csv' , 'text2.csv' , '....csv']
csvfiles = ['file1.csv' , 'file2.csv' , '....csv']

for file in txtfiles:
    with open( file , 'r') as in_file:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
        lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)

        #find the corresponding csv file you will write to 
        csvfile = csvfiles[textfiles.indexof(file)]

        with open(csvfile , 'w') as out_file:
                writer = csv.writer(out_file)
                #Input the header columns here
                writer.writerow(('header1' , 'header2' , '...'))
                writer.writerows(lines) #The lines is an array of lines that you have stripped
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for answering this question. I was thinking of adding an answer much like this, but you saved me some effort. You might want to take another look at this code. In the `open()`, should that really be `'log.txt'`? Might it be `file` instead?  Are the square brackets balanced in the `csvfile[textfiles`… expression? Finally, one of the crucial insights you are delivering is the use of the `csv` module. That's good.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are facing a problem in plotting data if is it so then import your csv file in form of pandas dataframe and then u can plot easily in python

Comment: The problem is extracting the data into csv file @Code wizard. I want to extract the input file data into csv file by using python, Because it's not just a single file its more than 40 to 50 files with same structure. and I need to run this same benchmark suite in different systems.